# Is it possible to show commerce product id's in the control panel?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, control-panel

For entries you can show the ID in control panel listings.

[image: entries ui in control panel]

I can't find a way to show craft commerce product ID's in a similar way in the control panel.

Commerce 3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not seem to be possible to select the ID as column to be shown in product overviews when clicking on the cogwheel on the left side.

You could use this extension https://plugins.craftcms.com/preparse-field to create a custom field into which you can "preparse" the product's ID. This field will then be available for selection.